# Smack user validation and Nodeprep profile of stringprep

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I'm working with Smack library and as I understand there is no function for verifying user jid, which is used in creating new Connection. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

So I decided to write a new one and for this purpose I started to investigate [RFC-6122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6122#page-4) which contains ABNF block with validation rules.

Unfortunately I'm not very aware of very-Unicode specific things and BNF-related things, so I didn't understand how to make correct regular expression according to this BNF block. Especially I'm confused by such thing as "Nodeprep profile of stringprep" mentioned in ABNF block.

Could you please clarify this one or give me some advices?

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in RFC 6122, [Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6122#appendix-A), but that's unlikely to help you without also reading [RFC 3454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3454), and a bunch of other source material.  It's quite an undertaking to implement, so I strongly suggest you use an existing Stringprep library, such as [libidn](http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/javadoc/).